# how can i create dynamic shapes in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a dynamic triangle, such that a user is able to grab either a vertex or side and move it. The angle should get updated in real-time. Unfortunately, I have no clue how one can do that. I started out by simply drawing the triangle using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Triangle Canvas Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>

    <script>
    var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
    var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

    
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
    context.arc(400, 100, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.stroke();
    context.font = "15px Comic Sans MS";
    context.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText("81", 390, 140);
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(200, 300, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.strokeStyle ='red';
    context.stroke();
    context.font = "15px Comic Sans MS";
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText("49", 230, 300);
    
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(520, 400, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    context.strokeStyle ='#008000';
    context.stroke();
    context.font = "15px Comic Sans MS";
    context.fillStyle = "#008000";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText("50", 500, 385);
    
    // the triangle
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(400, 100);
    context.lineTo(200, 300);
    context.lineTo(520, 400);
    context.closePath();
    

    // the outline
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#666666';
    context.stroke();

    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

to get the following image. [please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXAmi.png)

the problem is that my code is purely hardcoded, the angle value, the circle, and the triangle. My approach is probably wrong because I cannot see how one can turn all that into one dynamic image. I tried googling to see if someone created something similar but I was unable to find anything useful. Some insight on how to approach this problem would be great (a Youtube video or article would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: The problem is, that canvas contains pixels only, it's an image, there's no live objects in a canvas. You've to implement a model of the objects, and add a mousedown listener on the canvas, and programmatically determine (by comparing the mouse coordinates to your JS model of the "objects" in the canvas), whether the mouse is over a drawn "object". This would be a lot easier with [<svg>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created dynamic trinagle but i don't know math. Hope I help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trinagle</title>
    
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    
    <script>
        let mousePosition = [0, 0];
        let mouseClicked = false;
        let dragged = null;

        const getMousePosition = (canvas, event) => {
            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = Math.min(Math.max(event.clientX - rect.left, 0), canvas.width);
            const y = Math.min(Math.max(event.clientY - rect.top, 0), canvas.width);

            return [x, y];
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
                mousePosition = getMousePosition(canvas, event);
            });

            document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseClicked = true); 
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseClicked = false); 
            
            const points = [
                [50, 200, '#f00'],
                [150, 50, '#0f0'],
                [200, 150, '#00f'],
            ];
            
            const radius = 10;
            
            const draw = () => {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                
                const [mX, mY] = mousePosition;
                
                for (const [index, [x, y, color]] of points.entries()) {
                    const hovered = (mX - x) ** 2 + (mY - y) ** 2 < radius ** 2;
                    const style = hovered ? 'fill' : 'stroke';

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
                    
                    ctx[`${style}Style`] = color;
                    ctx[style]();
                    
                    if(hovered && mouseClicked) {
                        dragged = index;
                    }
                    
                    if(dragged === index) {
                        points[index] = [...mousePosition, color];
                        
                        if(!mouseClicked) dragged = null;
                    }
                }
                
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
                ctx.lineTo(points[1][0], points[1][1]);
                ctx.lineTo(points[2][0], points[2][1]);
                ctx.lineTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
                ctx.stroke();

                window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            }
            
            window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```